# Can I search documents and add any js files I find to a bundle in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So we're making a website with plugins, and I'm wondering if I can just search the plugins folder for any js files and add them to a bundle all within the *BundleConfig.cs* class.

I've thought about naming all the files I want to bundle like `Plugin.pluginName.js`, and then searching through all the files looking for any files that match  "*Plugin.*.js*", but I'm not sure how exactly to do that.

How would one create a plugins bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea about naming all the files you want to bundle following a naming convention is a good convention to follow.

Add a script bundle to the bundle collection

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins").Include(
            "~/Scripts/*.Plugin.js")); //{pluginName}.Plugin.js convention

    //...other bundles
}
```

You can also search the plugins folder for any js files if you want to forgo the naming conventions

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Plugin‌​s", "*.Plugin.js", true));
    //above recursively search subdirectories of directoryVirtualPath.

    //...other bundles
}
```

In the view reference the bundle using the name registered like

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins")
```

Reference [Using Bundling and Minification with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: So using `"~/Plugins/*.Plugin.js"` seems to only search through the immediate contents of the `~/Plugins` folder. I need to search through each immediate sub-folder, like `"~/Plugins/*/*.Plugin.js"`, but you can't use that because wildcards can only be in the last section (where the file name is).

Comment: the include method uses params. you can use system.io to get all the plugin directories and construct the templates to give to the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I found the solution! You can use the `IncludeDirectory()` method in lieu of the `Include()` method like so: `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins").IncludeDirectory("~/Plugins", "*.Plugin.js", true));` Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**What is Bundling?**

Bundling is a new feature in ASP.NET 4.5 that makes it easy to combine or bundle multiple files into a single file. 
You can create CSS, JavaScript and other bundles. Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests and that can improve first page load performance.

**How to enable bundling?**

Bundling is enabled or disabled by setting the value of the debug attribute in the compilation Element in the Web.config file. In the following XML, debug is set to true so bundling and minification is disabled.
XML

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />

</system.web>
```

To enable bundling and minification, set the debug value to "false".

You can override the Web.config setting with the EnableOptimizations property on the BundleTable class. 
The following code enables bundling and minification and overrides any setting in the Web.config file.

**Example**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {


    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AnyName").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Plugins/*.js"));    // this will all the files in the plugins folder with .js extension
                                           //you can specify files separately if dont want to use wildcards

      BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

**Important Note:** The virtual path specified in the Include method and the search pattern in the IncludeDirectory method **can accept one "*" wildcard character as a prefix or suffix to in the last path segment**.

Offical doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-mvc

Thanks

Karthik